# Reemplazar imágenes en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Saludos, estoy creando un botón que muestre una carta aleatoria en **Javascript**, pero quiero saber cómo puedo reemplazar una carta nueva por la que tenía anteriormente en el *div* de salida ya que al activar el botón, se crea la nueva debajo de la anterior. Adjunto código y agradezco de antemano las respuestas.

```
<button onclick="sacar();">Sacar carta</button>
<div id="cartaOutput">
Aquí va la imagen de la carta

</div>
<input type="hidden" id="cartaHidden"/> <!--En este input va un valor que es con el que mando llamar a la carta-->
```

Ahora va el Javascript

```
function sacar()
{

document.getElementById("cartaHidden").value = Math.floor((Math.random()*42)+1); //Genero el número aleatorio
var carta=document.getElementById("cartaHidden").value; //Esto me permite pasar el valor del número random a una variable

var cartaOutput=document.getElementById("cartaOutput"); 
var salida=document.createElement("IMG"); 
    salida.setAttribute("src", ""+carta+".png");
cartaOutput.appendChild(salida); //Aquí muestro la imagen

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta agregando un elemento img por defecto para luego modificarle el atributo `src`.

En html, le indicamos la imagen por defecto:

```
<button onclick="sacar();">Sacar carta</button>
<div id="cartaOutput">
  <img style="display:none" id="imagen-carta" /> <!--elemento donde se cargaran las imagenes-->
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="cartaHidden"/>
```

Le asignamos el `display:none` debido que no hay imagen inicial cuando carga la etiqueta y no queremos que muestre un error.

Ahora en el js, en vez de crear, buscamos el elemento imagen-cargar y le asignamos el atributo `src` y le indicamos que muestre la imagen ya cargada:

```
function sacar()
    {

    document.getElementById("cartaHidden").value = Math.floor((Math.random()*42)+1); //Genero el número aleatorio
    var carta=document.getElementById("cartaHidden").value; //Esto me permite pasar el valor del número random a una variable

    var cartaOutput=document.getElementById("cartaOutput"); 
    var salida=document.getElementById("imagen-carta"); 
    salida.setAttribute("src", ""+carta+".png"); // en vez de crear, le asignamos el attr src a la imagen ya existente.
     salida.style.display = "block";

    }
```

Ejemplo funcionado:

```js
var cartas = [
'',
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgOXu.png?s=48&g=1",
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png",
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d55j.png"
]
function sacar()
    {

    document.getElementById("cartaHidden").value = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1); //Genero el número aleatorio
    var carta=document.getElementById("cartaHidden").value; //Esto me permite pasar el valor del número random a una variable

    var cartaOutput=document.getElementById("cartaOutput"); 
    var salida=document.getElementById("imagen-carta"); 
    salida.setAttribute("src", ""+cartas[carta]+".png"); // en vez de crear, le asignamos el attr src a la imagen ya existente.
     salida.style.display = "block";

    }
```

```html
<button onclick="sacar();">Sacar carta</button>
<div id="cartaOutput">
  <img style="display:none" id="imagen-carta" /> <!--elemento donde se cargaran las imagenes-->
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="cartaHidden"/>
```

Comment: Ese tag ¿funciona con el nombre de carta dinámico? Porque yo mando llamar a la carta con la variable carta concatenada a su extensión png en el Javascript

Comment: Si. Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Ya lo pruebo, gracias de antemano y voto positivo.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, marcada como respuesta correcta. ¡Gracias!